# Cannot call other functions in the same Typescript file

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, esmodules

I'm importing function from a Typescript file:
`import { myExportedFunction } from '../utils/myFile';`

The `myExportedFunction` function calls a non-exported function in the same file:

```
const myNonExportedFunction = () => {
    ... code ...
}

export const myExportedFunction = () => {
    myNonExportedFunction();

    ... more code ...
}
```

When I run it, I get: `Uncaught Reference error: 'myNonExportedFunction' is not defined`. If I replace the function call with the code inside `myNonExportedFunction`, everything works.
Why am I getting this error? Context: this code is for a chrome plugin.

tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "Node16",
    "moduleResolution": "Node16",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

webpack.config:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        index: [
            "regenerator-runtime/runtime.js",
            path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "Index.tsx"),
        ],
        background: path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "background.ts"),
        "content-scripts": path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "content-scripts.ts"),
        "ninjas-content-script": path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "ninjas-content-script.ts"),
    },
    output: {
        filename: "[name].js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    },
    plugins: [
        new CopyWebpackPlugin({
            patterns: [{ from: "public" }],
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: "index.html",
            chunks: ["index"],
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: 'styles/[name].css',
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"],
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "ts-loader",
                        options: {
                            compilerOptions: {noEmit: false},
                        },
                    },
                ],
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"],
            },
        ],
    },
};
```

Comment: I suspect it has to do with hoisting. It could be a bug or a limitation in node 16 format but then it should cause an error in TS if that's the case.

Comment: What can I try to do? I tried changing to es2015, but same thing. Maybe putting the functions in separate files would do the trick, but it is not really preferred.

Comment: just use standard functions.  It sounds like assigning anonymous functions to a const is the issue.  (It's not initialized until execution time... ) if you must use const anonymous functions, try changing the order.  (myExportedFunction declared first)

Comment: @pcalkins you did give me some hope, but unfortunately it did not help.

Comment: actually now that I look at this again... not sure it can work as const=anonymous function this way... remember neither function is initialized until it's executed... so when myExportedFunction gets called, it tries to initialize that anonymous function... but inside of that there's another anonymous function that has to be initiliazed.  (but that one hasn't executed yet so it's still undefined.)

Comment: I did try to use standard functions, but it did not help. I got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Got it to work by wrapping all the functions in another function.

```
export function myWrapperFunction() {
    // previously 'myNonExportedFunction'
    function myHelperFunction() {
        ... code ...
    }

   // previously 'myExportedFunction'
   function myFunction() {
        myHelperFunction();
      
        ... more code ...
    }

    myFunction();
}
```

This works as I only have one exported function in the file. If you have more than one exported function and both need to use the non-exported function, then I think the non-exported function must be duplicated or where the myFunction is called, some logic has to decide to call a suitable method.

Comment: You could also just export a class with your functions inside.  (probably easier to grok that way and you can use a constructor)  Either way they're all exported.

Comment: The easiest way would just be to use the `function` keyword to declare them.